# Get date prior to 30 days from today and prior to 12 months from today

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get date prior to 30 days from today and prior to 12 months from today. How Do I do that and format as mm/dd/yyyy

This is what I have done to set current date so far:

```
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                if (dd<10)
                dd = '0'+dd;

                if (mm<10)
                mm = '0'+mm;

                today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setDate` and `getDate` to determine the date 30 days ago.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
```

Same thing can be done for months with `getMonth` and `setMonth`.

Comment: Using *setMonth*, 31 July minus 1 month will be 31 June, which will roll over to 1 July.